# I have just written over my WAMP index.php! Anyone know how I can get another copy without re-installing WAMP

Tags: php, wamp

I've just written over my WAMP **index.php** ! Anyone know how I can get another copy without re-installing WAMP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried pasting the code here but the text-length limit reached. So, **take it from [codepad here](http://codepad.org/Ky2NI2YP).**

Comment: Thanks for the code but I am getting some Deprecated error and Notice can you please help me to remove that   This are the errors  Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 175

Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 178

Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 178

Notice: Undefined variable: aliasContents in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 178

Notice: Undefined variable: projectContents in on line 193

Notice: Undefined variable: phpExtContents in on line 204

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the wampserver files on SourceForge you may be able to find it, or a zip version of wampserver.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/

Comment: Thanks for the link but I am confused which version is mine and which one should I extract.Thanks in advance

Comment: Nope, they only have full exe versions.  No individual files.

Comment: Well that has changed.  You can probably get files through CVS if you know how to use it.  Or you can just run the exe files because, for the most part, it's just a self extracting archive.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me: http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/234875-ive-lost-the-indexphp-for-wampserver-2/

The codepad link had deprecated code.