# How do I get default WAMP page?

Tags: php, firefox, wamp

Few hours ago I installed two different firefox versions in order to test my web applications. But it was kind of hectic and I uninstalled everything and reinstalled firefox latest version. Now I am only using the most latest firefox version. After reinstalling latest firefox I launched my WAMP server. Earlier when I type localhost in the web browser it showed me a page similar to below image
[image]

But now when I am launching firefox I am getting a page similar to below. **I remember there was an index.php file in www directory. That file is also missing. But I am pretty sure that I did not intentionally delete the file**
[image]

What has really happened? All my other browsers (chrome) display the same thing (similar to 2nd image)
How do I get that default wamp page?

Comment: Similar problem with possible solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690207/i-have-just-written-over-my-wamp-index-php-anyone-know-how-i-can-get-another-co

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index.php file generates the 'previous' page, but that file is missing. Reinstalling WAMP should do the job!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to find in this link :

```
...\wampp\htdocs\index.php
```

... = folder path that you save wampp application,
actualy you can also create that .php file in that path and test it.